# Terminating a thread with a spinlock (Critical Section)

Tags: c++, windows, spinlock

i am using critical sections within a thread to make sure the value the values do not break, but in the documentation it states that terminating a thread while it has entered the critical section is an undefined behaviour so you will no longer be able to enter it afterwards.

is there something else that i can use that is immune to this issue (somehow)?

Comment: Get your thread to exit the critical section. Communicate with it with whatever mechanism you have, atomic flags, future/promise, semaphores...

Comment: Terminating a thread is itself already pretty much undefined behavior. You need to get the thread to exit cleanly. Terminating it will leave a mess behind (critical sections are just one of many problems that will arise).

Comment: C++ has destructors, so that you don't have to exit a thread procedure while holding any resources, like a critical section.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I understand now. I suppose I could implement my own thread wrapper inside of a class that gets the thread to finish a lap before it exists in order to make sure my ExitCriticalSection call is being done correctly